# ThreeJS - Transform by applyMatrix4 doesn't preserve eigen vector's direction

Tags: three.js, 3d, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I transformed a vector which lays on the transformation matrix's eigen space using `Object3D.applyMatrix4`. I expected it not to move because the eigen value was 1, or at least stay on the eigen span, but it moved to an unexpected place.

I've made an sample project: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4x1ne)

But below is probably all the code you would need to examine

```js
let pointGeo = new THREE.Geometry()
pointGeo.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(1,-1,1)]
let pmat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0x00f0f0, size: 0.3})
let pointObj = new THREE.Points(pointGeo, pmat)
let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
matrix.set( 1,  3,  3, 0,
           -3, -5, -3, 0,
            3,  3,  1, 0,
            0,  0,  0, 1)
pointObj.applyMatrix4(matrix)
```

[image]

Specifically I'm transforming a point `(1, -1, 1)` (where the purple square is) with a matrix. Multiplication by the matrix shouldn't change the value. (double checked by hand calculating) But it moves it to where the blue square is.

Is there other stages where some other transformation is applied? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that `Object3D.applyMatrix4` wasn't the right function for explicitly defining local matrix. I tried setting `Object3D.matrix` property directly and it worked. I changed code like this:

```js
o.matrix = mat
o.matrixAutoUpdate = false
o.updateMatrixWorld(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the source for applyMatrix4... are you hand applying your matrix exactly like this:

````
        applyMatrix4 ( m ) {

            var x = this.x, y = this.y, z = this.z;
            var e = m.elements;

            var w = 1 / ( e[ 3 ] * x + e[ 7 ] * y + e[ 11 ] * z + e[ 15 ] );

            this.x = ( e[ 0 ] * x + e[ 4 ] * y + e[ 8 ] * z + e[ 12 ] ) * w;
            this.y = ( e[ 1 ] * x + e[ 5 ] * y + e[ 9 ] * z + e[ 13 ] ) * w;
            this.z = ( e[ 2 ] * x + e[ 6 ] * y + e[ 10 ] * z + e[ 14 ] ) * w;

            return this;

        },
    ```
````